# Is it possible to load additional events into a Google Calendar from an ICS URL?

Tags: google-calendar, sharing

I have a list of courses that I publish as an ICS file and have a Google Calendar that uses its URL as a source. This works very well.

What I would like to be able to do is take a standard Google Calendar and be able to add a URL as an input so that the single calendar will show my own events I create and the events from the ICS URL.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this, I couldn't see an obvious way?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what exactly you want to do.

If you want to add events from an external calendar to one of your calendars in GCal, you can do it only on case-by-case basis. Even a third-party tool won't help you with such a sync because if you import an event from a remote calendar and then delete the event in the remote calendar, it will stay in your GCal (iCal compares content not revisions).

If you just want to display a remote calendar in the same view as your primary calendar, follow these steps:

1. Click on the arrow to the right of `Other calendars` in the side bar
2. Click on `Add by URL`
3. Paste the URL and click `Add Calendar`

[image]

Note: `Import calendar` option in the screenshot is that case-by-case import to add events to your primary calendar.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this facility, but what I'd like to be able to do is add some events via url but still be able to add extra ones myself

Comment: @TobyAllen: Could you please be specific about the direction of adding/removing events? Your main calendar in Google Calendar is local and everything else is remote.